# Why is $\partial_\nu\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$?

Tags: tensors

I must admit: I've no idea about tensor calculus, I just started to read some basics about contraction and index lowering/pushing. Still, I can't figure out why 
$\partial_\nu\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$ for an antisymmetric tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\partial_\nu\partial_\mu=\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$. This means
$$
\partial_\nu\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu}=-\partial_\mu\partial_\nu F^{\nu\mu}
$$
Now, the only difference between the first and the last expression is a renaming of the indices (which doesn't change anything) and a sign. So it's equal to its own negative, and therefore zero.

Comment: very nice explanation. Thx. BTW: can I write $\partial_\nu\partial_\mu$ as $\partial_{\nu\mu}$